# AngularJS update HTML when array is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this situation, on the HTML I'm using `ng-repeat="user in controller.users"` to display users on my page.

In JS I have:

```
Main.leaderboard(function(res) {
        vm.users = res;
    }, function() {
        $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
    });
```

After this when a user is register I'm using sockets to display on the page in real time:

```
    socket.on('player joined', function(data) {
        console.log('player ' + data.username +' joined');
        vm.users.push(data);
    });
```

I've tried with $digest but dosent work, it returns

> Uncaught TypeError: vm.users.$digest is not a function(anonymous
>   function)

Can someone explain how to update the HTML when the vm.users is updating?

Comment: use $timeout function..that will not conflict with digest cycle `$timeout(function(){vm.users.push(data);})`

Comment: What is `vm` in this case?  `var vm = this;`?

Comment: Why `controller.users` and not `vm.users`?

Comment: vm = this yes, @JeremyThille i'm using controller-as, thats why

Comment: @pankajparkar Uncaught TypeError: $timeout is not a function

Comment: inject $timeout in your app dependencies. `function($scope, $timeout){...`

Comment: @Hiero should I add an answer?

Comment: Already did so :) Gave you credit for it.

Comment: @Hiero check I've added an answer,,thank for credit  Jeremy Thille

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$timeout` function that will ensure that your digest will run without conflicting with other running digest cycle.

```
socket.on('player joined', function(data) {
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log('player ' + data.username +' joined');
        vm.users.push(data);
    })
});
```

**Note**

> Don't forget to add `$timeout` dependency inside your controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that socket is "out of Angular's world".

As Pankajparkar said, put it "in Angular's world" by using [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) :

```
socket.on('player joined', function(data) {
    $timeout( function(){ // $timeout is part of Angular. You don't need to give it a delay.
        vm.users.push(data); // Now Angular is aware of that.
    });
});
```

In order to use $timeout, you need to inject it in your controller :

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout){...
```